# Img won't centre align - email

Tags: html, css, email

Having an issue getting an image at the top of an email to center align. I believe it is to do with a piece of code that makes the image vanish when the browser is greater than 520px. Though I need this code for the rest of email. How can I create an exception so this particular image remains central?

```
.mobile {
    display: none !important;
    font-size 0 !important;
    max-height: 0 !important;
    line-height: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    mso-hide: all !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.mobile img {
    max-height: 0 !important;
    width: 0 !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    *[class=hide] {
        display: none !important;
    }
    [class=mobile] {
        display: block !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
    *[class=mobile] img {
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

.

```
<td class="mobile" style="font-size: 0; mso-hide: all; width:120px; height:24px;"><div align="center"><a href="~PROBE(201)~"><img border="0" height="24" width="120" src="images/MH-logo.png" /></a></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

the "align" is deprecated in HTML5 and might not be supported in the browser/email.

Try this in your div

<div style="text-align:center">

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I should have looked  closer.

Most likely the reason is the lack of complete HTML for the TD tag.

```
<table style="width:100%"><tr>
<td class="mobile" style="font-size: 0; mso-hide: all; width:120px; height:24px;"><div align="center"><a href="~PROBE(201)~"><img border="0" height="24" width="120" src="images/MH-logo.png" /></a></div></td>
</tr></table>
```

**ALSO**

I commented out everything that does not make sense

```
<style>
.mobile {
/*  display: none !important;   Do Display, No image */
    font-size 0 !important;
/*  max-height: 0 !important;  */
/*  line-height: 0 !important; */
    margin: 0 !important;
/*  mso-hide: all !important;  not CSS , this is Microsoft Office code */ 
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.mobile img {
 /*   max-height: 0 !important;   no height, No image */
 /*   width: 0 !important;   no width, no image   */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    *[class=hide] {
        display: none !important;
    }
    [class=mobile] {
/*      display: block !important; */
/*      max-height: none !important; */ 
        margin: 0px !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
 *[class=mobile] img {
       display: block !important;
/*      width: 100% !important; */
/*      height: auto !important; */
/*      max-height: none !important;  */
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
}
</style>

<table style="width:100%"><tr>
<td class="mobile" style="font-size: 0; XXXXmso-hide: all; width:120px; height:24px;"><div align="center"><a href="~PROBE(201)~"><img border="0" height="24" width="120" src="images/MH-logo.png" /></a></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: updated my answer  , please note: the use of "!important" in CSS is a "LAST RESORT" , so I strongly suggest not using it.  if you must override another CSS entry you can make the entry more specific, Like:  
div.xyz td.mobile {SomeCss to change}

Comment: Hi Philip, a lot of that code is from something that was given to me to make images disappear and appear depending on whether it is desktop and mobile within emails. I believe the "mso-hide: all" was put in by the original coder to ensure support on older versions of outlook which rely on word. It seems to work, so I would rather not rip up what they did. Also sadly fixing the TD did not seem to centre align the image.

Comment: At this point, I'm stabbing in the dark without an example of a minimal "full" email example and what email program it is not working with. if it fails with all email programs, then a exported .EML file might be useful to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Give certain width and add this css

```
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
```

Should solve your issue.

Comment: Did you put that in the surrounding td tag or in the img tag? As neither seemed to work for me.

Comment: Give width 100% to parent tag , and less than 100% width to the img tag.